# Determine how many days a certificate is still valid from within bash script

Tags: bash, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to check how many days the certificate of a website is valid from within a bash script which runs on a standard Ubuntu 14.04 server. openssl is available.

I already figured out that I can use openssl to get the target date

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -noout -enddate
notAfter=Dec 22 16:37:00 2016 GMT
```

But how do I parse the resulting date and subtract the current one? Or might there be a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in single line

```
echo "(" $(date -d "`openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/d-herrmann.de/cert.pem -text -noout | grep "Not After" | cut -c 25-`" +%s) - $(date -d "now" +%s) ")" / 86400 | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `date`'s `%j` to get day of the year and arithmetic expansion for subtraction:

```
$ echo $(( $(date -d "$(cut -d= -f2 <(echo 'notAfter=Dec 22 16:37:00 2016 GMT'))" '+%j') - $(date '+%j')))
73
```

- `$(date -d "$(cut -d= -f2 <(echo 'notAfter=Dec 22 16:37:00 2016 GMT'))" '+%j')` gets us the day of the year from the date we have got, replace teh `echo` command inside process substitution, `<(echo 'notAfter=Dec 22 16:37:00 2016 GMT')` with the `openssl` command you have used initially
- `$(date '+%j')` gets us today's date as day of the year
- `$(())` is used for subtracting the integers

Comment: Using `%j` does not work as it does not take into account what year it is. It only works if the dates are in the same year. When a certificate expires in January but it is still December of the previous year, this would give an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
date1="Dec 22 16:37:00 2016 GMT"                          # Future date
date2=$(date)                                             # Current date
diff=$(($(date -d "$date1" +%j)-$(date -d "$date2" +%j))) #Diff between two date, %j is to show day of the year.
echo $diff                                                #Display difference             
73
```

Or just in one line:

```
 echo $(($(date -d "Dec 22 16:37:00 2016 GMT" +%j)-$(date +%j)))
 73
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script, which returns `days`, `hours` or `minutes` a cert is still valid, I just saved it in an executable file e.g. `check_cert_age.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# input domain as first parameter eg. ./heck_cert_age.sh stackoverflow.com
input="$1"
domain=$(echo "$input" | sed -e 's|^[^/]*//||' -e 's|/.*$||')
#domain=stackoverflow.com

echo 
echo "Check the cert of Domain $domain"

datetime=$(timeout 5 openssl s_client -servername $domain -connect $domain:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates | sed 's/notAfter=\(.*\)$/\1/' | tail -n1)

if [ -z "$datetime" ]; then
    echo
    echo "ERROR"
    echo
    exit 0
fi

localtime=$(date -d "${datetime}" '+%R')
localdate=$(date -d "${datetime}" '+%Y-%m-%d')
timestamp=$(date -d "${datetime}" '+%s')
now=$(date '+%s')
diff=$((($timestamp-$now)/60))
if [ "$diff" -gt 3599 ] || [ "$diff" -lt 3599 ]; then
   diffstr="$(expr $diff / 60 / 24) days"
elif [ "$diff" -gt 59 ] || [ "$diff" -lt 59 ] ; then
   diffstr="$(expr $diff / 60) h"
else
   diffstr="$diff min"
fi

echo 
echo "The cert is valid until $localdate at $localtime ($diffstr)"
echo
```

The output will be:

> Check the cert of Domain stackoverflow.com
>
> The cert is valid until 2023-02-01 at 15:10 (50 days)

The output make a difference in `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and knows the difference to the local timezone. For minutes, it would look e.g. like that:

> Check the cert of Domain ssl-cert-almost-expired.com
>
> The cert is valid until 2022-12-13 at 15:39 (34 min)